# Unable to parse url encoded data in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-encoding, body-parser

I have this super simple server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/update', (req, resp) => {
  debugger;
  resp.send();
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I am sending data to the server like this:

[image: Postman screenshot]

REPL shows me an empty body when the request is received:

```
> req.body
{}
```

I would expect the body to look something like this:

```
{
  "hello": "world"
}
```

Am I missing something obvious ? Probably ..

Comment: I just looked up ``debugger;``. I never knew you could do that in node.js before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By choosing `x-form-urlencoded` below postman will send the Content-Type header for you, you dont need to specify it again yourself. You can see this by clicking the Preview button. So you're sending a duplicate Content-Type header which seems to trip up body parser.